# How to count large number of files from directory and subdirectory (like root C:// or D://)

Tags: java

I am writing a code to count file with specific extension from folder and it subfolder. this code work well when i count from small and medium large folder.

the problem start if i count from root, example from D:// . it will count for some time but stop at the middle. i assume the code is not efficient to read large number of files and folder.

```
public static int countFiles(File directory, String ext) {
    int count = 0;

    for(File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        System.out.println(file);
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
            count += countFiles(file, ext); 
        }
     String textFile = file.toString();
     if(textFile.endsWith(ext)){
         count++;
     }
    }
```

**error appear**

[image]

**screenshot line error**

[image]

- here is my full code [CLICK HERE](http://pastebin.com/BDQyFRUu)

Comment: If the `File` is not a valid file reference, calling `listFiles` will return a `null` result.  Use `File#exists` to be sure that the `File` reference exists or not before you try and read the directory...Also, `File` does not like things like short cuts or symbolical links (or function joints or windows special folders)

Comment: Which lines are line 77 and 79?

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's still not enough, because another program might delete the file after your `exists` check but before `listFiles`.

Comment: @immibis Yeah, but at least you have the list files which use to reside within the directory, another check to the child file's `exist` method will also highlight the issue

Comment: The errors on line 77, which is the `for loop`, see my first comment

Comment: @MadProgrammer no; in the case I mentioned `listFiles` will return null, and then iterating over it will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: So you're suggesting between calling `exists` and `listFiles` the directory is removed. That's a valid case, but then you'd be screwed none-the-less, there would simply be little you could do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is that `directory.listFiles()` is returning null.

Despite not being mentioned in the documentation, this can happen if you don't have sufficient access rights to list the directory contents.  You can pretty easily fix this as shown below.

Also, there is a slight logic error in that (for example) a directory named `Files ending with .xls` can also get counted as a file, when it clearly isn't.  I've fixed this too.

```
public int countFiles(File directory, String... exts) {
  int count = 0;
  File[] files = directory.listFiles();
  if (files != null) {
    for (File file : files) {
      if (file.isDirectory()) {
        count += countFiles(file, exts);
      } else {
        String textFile = file.toString();
        for (String ext : exts) {
          if (textFile.endsWith(ext)) {
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply check for nulls at the start of countFiles.

```
public int countFiles(File directory, String... exts) {
  if (directory == null) return 0;
```

If you're doing a large recursive scan of the entire file system -- it makes sense that a directory could no longer exist between the time `countFiles(file, exts);` is called and when `directory.listFiles()` is called.